# Windows Store app wrapping checkbox text

Tags: wpf, xaml, checkbox, windows-store-apps

I have a layout in which I have four checkboxen which I'd like to show in horizontal arrangement if they fit, and if they don't wrap them to an another line.

I'm using WrapGrid inside a ListView as follows:

```
<ListView  Width="Auto">
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
      <ItemsPanelTemplate>
         <WrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal" MaximumRowsOrColumns="4"/>
      </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <CheckBox IsChecked="True" Content="Short text"/>
    <CheckBox IsChecked="True" Content="Longer text (with explanation)" />
    <CheckBox  Content="Some other longer stuff" />
    <CheckBox  Content="ABCDEDFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"/>
</ListView>
```

[image]

It's almost behaving as it's supposed to, but for some reason it's clipping text from my checkboxes, setting all of them to have the same width as the first one (`Short text` in my example). I could solve this by having the checkbox with the longest text first, but I'd really like to have the ListView figure out the width of the widest item by itself. Is that possible?

Comment: I guess it's not possible with `WrapGrid` since it always picks first item size. You can read more about it [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/07229c77-34be-4b93-8adb-4149206e965e/how-do-i-dynamically-stretch-the-contents-of-a-wrapgrid-as-the-itempanel-of-a-gridview?forum=winappswithcsharp).

Comment: Converted to an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>Use **`WrapPanel`** and set **`ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"`** on **ListView** so that it automatically wraps in case element cannot be fit within given space.</strike>

```
<ListView Width="Auto" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <CheckBox IsChecked="True" Content="Short text"/>
    <CheckBox IsChecked="True" Content="Longer text (with explanation)" />
    <CheckBox  Content="Some other longer stuff" />
    <CheckBox  Content="ABCDEDFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"/>
</ListView>
```

I would keep the above content here so that if someone stumbles upon this post for WPF, above solution will work in that case.

---

**UPDATE** for Windows Store App:

It's not possible with **`WrapGrid`** since it always picks first item size. You can read more about it [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/07229c77-34be-4b93-8adb-4149206e965e/how-do-i-dynamically-stretch-the-contents-of-a-wrapgrid-as-the-itempanel-of-a-gridview?forum=winappswithcsharp).

Comment: WrapPanel is unfortunately not available for Windows Store apps